# My rake db:migrate is failing and I can't figure out how to fix it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

when I run the rake db:migrate I get this

```
Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
...sion_store :cookie_store, key:
```

Now I'm running it on a fresh ubutu box. 
$ rails -v = Rails 3.1.3
$ ruby -v  = ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]

The file I get error on contains some comments and this line of code

```
Edm2::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_edm2_session'
```

Notes... 
I'm not calling $ sudo rake db:migrate. so the like questions up here doesn't have the answer.
what I've read indicates that the hash is wrong, and putting in the old one seems to stop the bleeding.. But I don't want a hymopheliactic application where I am stopping the bleeding all over. I'd rather know what's causing the issue and fix it at the source.

---

It might help the "helpers" to mention that if I call $rails new demo the file session_store has a different format.. it seems to use the old hash markings... this might be a clue to some, but it is just a pointer to this newb

Comment: Are you sure Rails is running with Ruby 1.9.2? Does switching to `:ccokie_store, :key => '_edm2_session'` do anything useful?

Comment: I'm not sure it's running 1.9.2, but that's what it's telling me when I type.. ruby -v.. I pasted it right from the terminal.

Comment: If I change the hash to the 1.8 style it works... and newly created projects have the 1.8 style too. Not sure why they would.

Comment: So Rails is running under Ruby 1.8. Do you have any `.rvmrc` files?

Comment: Nope.... I don't even know what they are

Comment: Somehow you're running Rails with Ruby 1.8, I can't think of anything right now though.